# Unity download a video from server and save it

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I want to fetch a video from my server and save it in my assests to view it later in my game. I am aware of use of www. but i dont understand how to download the video from my server giving it's url. below is the code to get video as a texture.

```
    var www = new WWW("http://Sameer.com/SampleVideo_360x240_2mb.mp4");
    var movieTexture = www.movie;
```

Any idea how do I save the mp4 file ?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

### Using UnityWebRequest API.

You can use [UnityWebRequest](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Networking.UnityWebRequest.html)

```cs
    public class VideoDownloader: MonoBehaviour {
        void Start() {
            StartCoroutine(DownloadVideo());
        }

        IEnumerator DownloadVideo() {
            UnityWebRequest www = UnityWebRequest.Get("https://example.com/video.mp4");
            yield return www.SendWebRequest();

            if(www.isNetworkError || www.isHttpError) {
                Debug.Log(www.error);
            } else {
                File.WriteAllBytes("path/to/file", www.downloadHandler.data);
            }
        }
    }
```

### Using obsolete WWW API.

You can use [WWW.bytes](http://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/WWW-bytes.html) to get the raw data for movie file, and save that. Something like:

```cs
    var www = new WWW("http://Sameer.com/SampleVideo_360x240_2mb.mp4");
    File.WriteAllBytes("path/to/file", www.bytes);
```

Comment: Thanks Smilediver let me try this :) And when i want to show the movie ? how will i retrieve it ?

Comment: Thanks I figured out how to use it.

Comment: @SameerHussain, how did you end up loading this back in from the save file? When you load it back, can you access it through www.movie as usual? I'll give it a go like that and comment back, so other users have an answer.

Comment: @BioeJD, on some platforms WWW class supports `file://` protocol, so you can do something like `new WWW("file:///path/to/cached/file.mp4")`. Also you should be able to use regular .Net file IO to read the file from disk, eg `var bytes = File.ReadAllBytes("/path/to/cached/file.mp4")`.

Comment: WWW is deprecated - what's the latest on this?