# Download Vimeo videos for offline use using Unity Vimeo API

Tags: unity-game-engine, vimeo

I am currently using the Unity Vimeo API to stream videos but is there a way to download and store the videos at a particular resolution such as 720p so that they can be used offline?

Answer (score 0):

This is currently not supported in the Vimeo Unity SDK, but we will consider that for our roadmap.

[This answers a similar question](https://stackoverflow.com/a/33873144/10056175) and describes a way to save the videos yourself and load them back for offline playback.