# How to play videos hosted on a server in unity

Tags: c#, arrays, unity-game-engine, webserver, video-player

I have a video player that plays an array of videos hosted in a videos folder. I'm able to delete and add videos and it updates in the video player fine. I'd like to host these videos on a web server. Can any one point me in the right direction to have this completed.

Code:

```
public VideoClip[] videoClips;

     videoClips = Resources.LoadAll<VideoClip>("Videos");
     videoPlayer.clip = videoClips[0];
     videoplayername();
```

Any assistance would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Unity download a video from server and save it](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33872545/unity-download-a-video-from-server-and-save-it)